# How to check for outliers using scalars

Tags: stata

I'm checking the distribution of test scores by year, subject, and grade. I want to make sure that there aren't any outliers, which would be anything more than 4 standard deviations from the mean. This is my code:

```
bys year subject tested_grade: summarize test_score
```

But when I try to get the scalars I can only get the scalar corresponding to the last year, subject, tested_grade. I've tried creating a loop but it leads to the same problem.

I have found Nick Cox's `extremes` command but it doesn't tell me how many standard deviations the extreme values are from the mean.

If anyone has some ideas of how to check for outliers as determined by a measure of standard deviations away from the mean it would be really helpful.

**Edit**

This code gets me (mostly) what I want.

```
bys year subject tested_grade: summarize test_score
gen std_test_score = (test_score > 4*r(sd)) if test_score < .
list test_score std_test_score if std_test_score==1
```

The only problem is that the last year, subject, and tested_grade is where the r(sd) comes from. I'd want to create a variable - std_test_score1-20 -  for each year, subject, and tested_grade.

Comment: "I have found Nick Cox's `extremes` command but it doesn't tell me how many std. deviations the extreme values are from the mean." That's **on purpose**: once you have possible outliers  the SD and mean are themselves affected and (value - mean)/SD is not a metric of outlierness!

Comment: Perhaps I should have added but I'm comparing my data with the means, max, min, and std that the data provider has published. My means, max, etc should match theirs and since my means are a little different I wanted to see if there are some outliers that might be causing the discrepancy.

Comment: Nothing stops you calculating (value - mean)/SD. How to do it depends on how means and SDs are held in your data or to be calculated from your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Means and SDs may be generated for several groups at once by

```
bysort year subject tested_grade : egen mean_test_score = mean(test_score) 
by year subject tested_grade: egen sd_test_score = sd(test_score) 
gen std_test_score = (test_score - mean_test_score) / sd_test_score
```

Indeed, `egen` has a function `std()` to do this in one step, but it's often a good idea to re-create basics from even more basic principles.

Your code omits subtraction of the mean.

However, as underlined in comments, (value - mean) / SD is a poor criterion for outliers as outliers themselves influence the mean and SD. That's why, for example, box plots are based on median, quartiles and (commonly) points more than so many interquartile ranges away from the nearer quartile.